# Does Vertica DB does support pipelining requests in one connection?

Tags: vertica, subquery

I want to know if Vertica DB does support pipeling request.
to be more explicit, if we can make multiple request in one shot.

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple request in one shot" ?

Answer (score 0):

Pipelined requests are possible in Vertica as long as you have a projection that is already sorted on the column you have as your predicate , the optimizer will use the faster GROUPBY PIPELINED operation.
 This shows up in your explain plan as **GROUPBY PIPELINED**, see example here:

```
=> EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT annual_income)    FROM customer_dimension  
   WHERE customer_gender = 'Female';

 Access Path: +-GROUPBY NOTHING [Cost: 161, Rows: 1] (PATH ID: 1)
 |  Aggregates: count(DISTINCT customer_dimension.annual_income)
 | +---> GROUPBY PIPELINED [Cost: 158, Rows: 10K] (PATH ID: 2)
 | |      Group By: customer_dimension.annual_income
 | | +---> STORAGE ACCESS for customer_dimension [Cost: 144, Rows: 47K] (PATH ID: 3)
 | | |      Projection: public.customer_dimension_DBD_1_rep_vmartdb_design_vmartdb_design_node0001
 | | |      Materialize: customer_dimension.annual_income
 | | |      Filter: (customer_dimension.customer_gender = 'Female')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean at the SQL statement level in a session.  In reality, this all depends on how you are sending the SQL statements. Like most databases, a single session executes a single SQL statement at a time.

Since I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, I'll address some possible questions and you can just edit your question if you want to be more specific.

If you want to run more than one SQL statement synchronously using vsql, then you just create a script with multiple SQL statements ended with a `;`.  If you aren't using vsql, then you'll just need to issue one statement at a time using whatever method you are using (programming language, ETL software, etc).

You might be talking about SQL Batching.  The ability to line up many SQL statements on a connection and execute them as a Batch to prevent the tedious back and forth communication.  [It does support that](https://my.vertica.com/docs/6.0.x/HTML/index.htm#14878.htm)

If you want to run more than one SQL statement in parallel, though, then you are going to have to open multiple sessions.